# What causes a rotating 3D object to get displaced unexpectedly?

Tags: pstricks, pst-solides3d

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-solides3d}
\psset
{
    object=parallelepiped,
    lightsrc=20 60 60 rtp2xyz,
    Decran=30,
    solidmemory,
    grid=false,
    incolor=red,
}
\begin{document}
\multido{\i=0+30}{12}{%
\begin{pspicture}[viewpoint=20 \i\space 20 rtp2xyz](-7,-3)(7,8)
    \psSolid[fillcolor=red,a=2,b=0.75,c=1.5,name=H2](0,-0.375,0.75)
    \psSolid[fillcolor=red,a=2,b=4,c=0.5,name=H1](0,2,0.25)
    \psSolid[fillcolor=green,a=2,b=0.75,c=1.5,name=H3](0,-0.375,2.25)
    \psSolid[fillcolor=green,a=2,b=4,c=0.5,name=H4](0,2,2.75)
\end{pspicture}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

## Question

What causes a rotating block 3D object to get displaced unexpectedly? And how to fix it?

Comment: Is it due to a fictitious force?

Comment: Hidden surfaces are not possible here, the reason why the order of drawing the four elements is important. It makes sense to create two prism by the edges.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-solides3d}
\psset
{
    object=parallelepiped,
    lightsrc=viewpoint,
    Decran=30,
    solidmemory,
    grid=false,
    incolor=red,
}
\begin{document}
\multido{\i=0+30}{12}{%
\begin{pspicture}[viewpoint=20 \i\space 20 rtp2xyz](-7,-3)(7,8)
   \ifnum\i>180
        \psSolid[fillcolor=red,a=2,b=4,c=0.5,name=H1](0,2,0.25)
        \psSolid[fillcolor=red,a=2,b=0.75,c=1.5,name=H2](0,-0.375,0.75)
        \psSolid[fillcolor=green,a=2,b=4,c=0.5,name=H4](0,2,2.75)
        \psSolid[fillcolor=green,a=2,b=0.75,c=1.5,name=H3](0,-0.375,2.25)
   \else
        \psSolid[fillcolor=red,a=2,b=0.75,c=1.5,name=H2](0,-0.375,0.75)
        \psSolid[fillcolor=red,a=2,b=4,c=0.5,name=H1](0,2,0.25)
        \psSolid[fillcolor=green,a=2,b=0.75,c=1.5,name=H3](0,-0.375,2.25)
        \psSolid[fillcolor=green,a=2,b=4,c=0.5,name=H4](0,2,2.75)
   \fi
\end{pspicture}}
\end{document}
```

[image]